# Validate 'not null' ManyToMany Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to make the ManyToMany member of Entity as "not null"

So I tried two patterns.

1) Adding @Assert\NotBlank()

```
/**
 * Many Users have Many Groups.
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PlaceCat", inversedBy="placeinfos")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="placeinfos_placecats")
 */
private $placeCats;
```

2) adding `required => true` in FormObject.

```
$formMapper
    ->add('placeCats',null,array('required' => true)
```

However, both are ignored.

Is it possible to set 'not null' restriction for ManyToMany Entity??

Comment: Are you sure that submitted data is null? maybe you are looking for @Assert\Count()?

Comment: THanks @Iwan Wijaya !!! it works perfect.

Answer (score 6):

ManyToMany with "not null" means you want at least 1? Then you need another Assert:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      min = "1",
 *      minMessage = "You have to select at least 1 item"
 * )
 */
```